# Change priorities of my own submitted jobs

Tags: lsf

I have many jobs running and pending.  I would like to indicate the relative priority of jobs that I have submitted to the queue, that are pending, but not yet running.  Is it possible to set this priority after submission?  Is it possible to set this priority before submission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move jobs that are pending with the btop command.

> btop job_ID | "job_ID[index_list]" [position]

If you add [position] it means that the job will be put at that place in the queue.

> By default, LSF dispatches jobs in a queue in the order of their
>   arrival (that is, first come, first served), subject to availability
>   of suitable server hosts.

Having said this, the priority of the job is unchanged. So you will only be able to change the order if the jobs have the same priority.
Depending on your LSF version, see the following links for details about btop

[LSF 10.1.0 > Command Reference > btop](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_command_ref/btop.1.html)

[LSF 9.1.3 > Command Reference > btop](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSETD4_9.1.3/lsf_command_ref/btop.1.html)